# Python; use list of initial characters to retrieve full word from other list?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to use the list of shortened words to select & retrieve the corresponding full word identified by its initial sequence of characters:

```
shortwords = ['appe', 'kid', 'deve', 'colo', 'armo']    

fullwords = ['appearance', 'armour', 'colored', 'developing', 'disagreement', 'kid', 'pony', 'treasure']
```

Trying this regex match with a single shortened word:

```
import re

shortword = 'deve'

retrieved=filter(lambda i: re.match(r'{}'.format(shortword),i), fullwords)

print(retrieved*)
```

returns

```
developing
```

So the regex match works but the question is how to adapt the code to iterate through the shortwords list and retrieve the full words?

EDIT: The solution needs to preserve the order from the shortwords list.

Comment: [`[f for f in fullwords if any(x in f for x in shortwords)]`](https://ideone.com/Ey3Yr9)

Comment: This doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: And what is "correct" in your understanding? I think the results are correct.

Comment: Needs to match the shortwords on the beginning characters only of the fullwords.  Also need to preserve the order of the shortwords list in the retrieved list.  Your example works on the data snippet provided but not when I test on the full data set in my app. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet has the functionality I wanted.  It builds a regular expression pattern at each loop iteration in order to accomodate varying word length parameters.  Further it maintains the original order of the wordroots list.  In essence it looks at each word in wordroots and fills out the full word from the dataset.  This is useful when working with the [bip-0039](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) words list which contains words of 3-8 characters in length and which are uniquely identifiable by their initial 4 characters.  Recovery phrases are built by randomly selecting a sequence of words from the bip-0039 list, order is important.  Observed security practice is often to abbreviate each word to a maximum of its four initial characters.  Here is code which would rebuild a recovery phrase from its abbreviation:

```
import re
wordroots = ['sun', 'sunk', 'sunn', 'suns']
dataset = ['sun', 'sunk', 'sunny', 'sunshine']
retrieved = []
for root in wordroots:
    #(exact match) or ((exact match at beginning of word when root is 4 or more characters) else (exact match))
    pattern = r"(^" + root + "$|" + ("^" + root + "[a-zA-Z]+)" if len(root) >= 4 else "^" + root + "$)")
    retrieved.extend( filter(lambda i: re.match(pattern, i), dataset) )
print(*retrieved)
```

Output:

```
sun sunk sunny sunshine
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one way to do it:

```
shortwords = ['appe', 'deve', 'colo', 'arm', 'pony', 'disa']
fullwords = ['appearance', 'developing', 'colored', 'armour', 'pony', 'disagreement']
        
# Dict comprehension
words = {short:full for short, full in zip(shortwords, fullwords)}

#Solving problem
keys = ['deve','arm','pony']
values = [words[key] for key in keys]
        
print(values)
```

This is a classical key - value problem. Use a dictionary for that or consider pandas in long-term.

Comment: Was hoping for something more pythonic and with the ability to control that the match is determined on the first four characters of the fullword ;-)

Comment: I indeed overlooked the four character constrain. This makes it actually even easier. Go for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a dictionary

```
# Using a dictionary 
test= 'appe is a deve arm'
shortwords = ['appe', 'deve', 'colo', 'arm', 'pony', 'disa']    
fullwords = ['appearance', 'developing', 'colored', 'armour', 'pony', 'disagreement']
#Building the dictionary 
d={}
for i in range(len(shortwords)):
    d[shortwords[i]]=fullwords[i]

# apply dictionary to test 
res=" ".join(d.get(s,s) for s in test.split()) 
# print test data after dictionary mapping
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question text seems to indicate that you're looking for your shortwords at the start of each word. That should be easy then:

```py
matched_words = [word for word in fullwords if any(word.startswith(shortword) for shortword in shortwords]
```

If you'd like to regex this for some reason (it's unlikely to be faster), you could do that with a large alternation:

```py
regex_alternation = '|'.join(re.escape(shortword) for shortword in shortwords)
matched_words = [word for word in fullwords if re.match(rf"^{regex_alternation}", word)]
```

Alternately if your shortwords are *always* four characters, you could just slice the first four off:

```py
shortwords = set(shortwords)  # sets have O(1) lookups so this will save
                              # a significant amount of time if either shortwords
                              # or longwords is long

matched_words = [word for word in fullwords if word[:4] in shortwords]
```

Comment: Interesting solutions, thanks.  When I tried them I noticed that I wanted to preserve the order in the shortwords list and these solutions yield results in the order of fullwords list.

Comment: @GoFaster that's not much harder, but it isn't clear what it is you want exactly. It also probably makes the solution less performant. You could try something like `result = {shortword: [fullword for fullword in fullwords if fullword.startswith(shortword)] for shortword in shortwords}` which will give you a dictionary of `shortword: [fullwords]` pairs. Does that help?

Comment: You could in fact then string these together with `list(*result.values())`